# How to ignore compiler flags automatically added with buildrpm

Tags: c++, c, makefile, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build a package with buildrpm.  My problem is that I have an *intentionally* vulnerable C program compiled when `make` is run normally as an example for the primary code (a fuzzer) to be tested on with `make check`.  When I try to build the rpm however, even though these vulnerable programs are not installed (as they're just tests), `rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/ansvif.spec` will still force it to compile it with `-Werror=format-security` which makes the build fail.  Is there a simple way around this -- beyond trying to rewrite the Makefile.am so that it's omitted with a certain flag passed by buildrpm if that's possible?  I'm looking for a proper solution to this problem, instead of something hacky, if possible.

Source code is at https://github.com/oxagast/ansvif

Comment: Just skip the `make test` part and it should work. Or avoid compiling the test programs when building the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "`%global _hardened_build 0`" towards the top of your specfile.

Answer (score -1):

There are other two options that come to mind:

1. Before running rpmbuild, export your own C_FLAGS. It might help you but it depends on the settings of your rpmbuild.
2. Use --define with the rpmbuild to declare your own optflags used with the builf. For instance rpmbuild -v -bb --clean --define 'optflags -foo -bar -foobar' ansvif.spec

Comment: Please format your answer properly and explain why your solution is the right one, rather than just stating what to do.